# Collect specific classes before running lint detector

Tags: android, kotlin, lint, android-lint

I want to write a lint check to ensure that `@ContributesAndroidInjector` was added to all fragments that need it.

Is there a way to gather all classes that are annotated with `@Module` before `visitClass(node: UClass)` is called?
Now I have manually added all modules in a list (see code example), but that is not the right solution for me as I would constantly need to update my detector when new modules are added.

Detector:

```
class MissingContributorDetector : Detector(), Detector.UastScanner {
    override fun getApplicableUastTypes(): List<Class<out UElement>> {
        return listOf(UClass::class.java)
    }

    override fun createUastHandler(context: JavaContext) = Visitor(context)

    class Visitor(private val context: JavaContext) : UElementHandler() {

        private val returnTypes: List<String>

        init {
            returnTypes = MODULES.mapNotNull { context.evaluator.findClass(it) }
                    .flatMap { it.methods.toList() }
                    .filter { it.hasAnnotation(DAGGER_MODULE_ANNOTATION) }
                    .mapNotNull { it.returnType }
                    .mapNotNull { PsiUtil.resolveClassInType(it)?.qualifiedName }
        }

        override fun visitClass(node: UClass) {
            // logic to determine if there is an issue
        }
    }

    companion object {
       private val MODULES = listOf(
           "com.dagger.module.ModuleOne",
           "com.dagger.module.ModuleTwo",
           "com.dagger.module.ModuleThree",
       )
    }
}
```

Module:

```
@Module
abstract class ModuleOne {

    @ContributesAndroidInjector
    abstract fun contributesFragment(): HomeFragment
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a way to gather all classes that are annotated with @Module before visitClass(node: UClass) is called?

The detector can be written to perform two passes. The first pass will collect all the class in a data structure which will be available to the detector during the second pass. In this scheme, `visitClass()` will be called for each class during the first and second passes.

**MissingContributorDetector.kt**

```
/*
    Process this lint check in two passes. The fist pass collects all the classes that have
    the @Module annotation. The second pass does the actual check but has a the class list
    produced in the first pass at its disposal.
 */
class MissingContributorDetector : Detector(), Detector.UastScanner {
    private val mModuleClasses: MutableList<UClass> = ArrayList()

    override fun getApplicableUastTypes(): List<Class<out UElement>> {
        return listOf(UClass::class.java)
    }

    override fun createUastHandler(context: JavaContext) = Visitor(context)

    // Cues up the second phase for the actual lint check.
    override fun afterCheckEachProject(context: Context) {
        super.afterCheckEachProject(context)
        if (context.phase == 1) { // Rescan classes
            context.requestRepeat(this, MissingContributorIssue.implementation.scope)
        }
    }

    inner class Visitor(private val context: JavaContext) : UElementHandler() {
        // Search for classes that are annotated with @Module
        override fun visitClass(node: UClass) {
            if (context.phase == 1) { // Just collect class names
                if (hasAnnotation(node.annotations, DAGGER_MODULE_ANNOTATION_QUALIFIED_NAME)) {
                    // Build the class list that will be used during the second pass.
                    mModuleClasses.add(node)
                }
            } else { // phase 2
                // Do whatever processing is necessary. Here we just check for
                // @ContributesAndroidInjector on each method in a class annotated with @Module.
                // The mModuleClasses structure is fully populated from the first pass.
                if (mModuleClasses.contains(node)) {
                    node.methods.forEach { checkMethodForContributesAndroidInjector(it) }
                }
            }
        }

        // Check for @ContributesAndroidInjector on non-constructor methods
        private fun checkMethodForContributesAndroidInjector(node: UMethod) {
            if (node.isConstructor ||
                    !isFragmentReturnType(node) ||
                    hasAnnotation(node.annotations, DAGGER_CONTRIBUTESANDROIDINJECTOR_QUALIFIED_NAME)) {
                return
            }
            context.report(
                    MissingContributorIssue,
                    node,
                    context.getNameLocation(node),
                    MissingContributorIssue.getExplanation(TextFormat.TEXT)
            )
        }

        private fun isFragmentReturnType(node: UMethod): Boolean {
            val returnTypeRef = node.returnTypeReference
            return returnTypeRef?.getQualifiedName() == HOME_FRAGMENT
        }

        private fun hasAnnotation(annotations: List<UAnnotation>, toCheck: String): Boolean {
            return annotations.any { it.qualifiedName == toCheck }
        }

    }

    companion object {
        const val DAGGER_MODULE_ANNOTATION_QUALIFIED_NAME = "dagger.Module"
        const val DAGGER_CONTRIBUTESANDROIDINJECTOR_QUALIFIED_NAME = "dagger.android.ContributesAndroidInjector"
        const val HOME_FRAGMENT = "com.dagger.module.HomeFragment"

        val MissingContributorIssue: Issue = Issue.create(
                id = "MissingContributesAndroidInjector",
                briefDescription = "Must specify @ContributesAndroidInjector",
                implementation = Implementation(
                        MissingContributorDetector::class.java,
                        Scope.JAVA_FILE_SCOPE),
                explanation = "Method must be annotated with @ContributesAndroidInjector if enclosing class is annotated with @Module.",
                category = Category.CORRECTNESS,
                priority = 1,
                severity = Severity.FATAL
        )
    }
}
```

---

---

**Old answer with just one pass**

The detector can be written to look at each class and to select only those classes that are annotated with `@Module`. Once a class is selected, each method that returns a `HomeFragment` can be checked for the `@ContributesAndroidInjector` annotation. Classes can then be added and scanned without updating a list of modules.

**MissingContributorDetector.kt**

```
class MissingContributorDetector : Detector(), Detector.UastScanner {

    override fun getApplicableUastTypes(): List<Class<out UElement>> {
        return listOf(UClass::class.java)
    }

    override fun createUastHandler(context: JavaContext) = Visitor(context)

    class Visitor(private val context: JavaContext) : UElementHandler() {

        // Search for classes that are annotated with @Module
        override fun visitClass(node: UClass) {
            if (hasAnnotation(node.annotations, DAGGER_MODULE_ANNOTATION_QUALIFIED_NAME)) {
                node.methods.forEach { checkMethodForContributesAndroidInjector(it) }
            }
        }

        // Check for @ContributesAndroidInjector on non-constructor methods
        private fun checkMethodForContributesAndroidInjector(node: UMethod) {
            if (node.isConstructor ||
                    !isFragmentReturnType(node) ||
                    hasAnnotation(node.annotations, DAGGER_CONTRIBUTESANDROIDINJECTOR_QUALIFIED_NAME)) {
                return
            }

            context.report(
                    MissingContributorIssue.ISSUE,
                    node,
                    context.getNameLocation(node),
                    MissingContributorIssue.ISSUE.getExplanation(TextFormat.TEXT)
            )
        }

        private fun isFragmentReturnType(node: UMethod): Boolean {
            val returnTypeRef = node.returnTypeReference
            return returnTypeRef?.getQualifiedName() == HOME_FRAGMENT
        }

        private fun hasAnnotation(annotations: List<UAnnotation>, toCheck: String): Boolean {
            return annotations.any { it.qualifiedName == toCheck }
        }
    }

    object MissingContributorIssue {
        private const val ID = "MissingContributesAndroidInjector"
        private const val DESCRIPTION = "Must specify @ContributesAndroidInjector"
        private const val EXPLANATION = ("Method must be annotated with @ContributesAndroidInjector if enclosing class is annotated with @Module.")
        private val CATEGORY: Category = Category.CORRECTNESS
        private const val PRIORITY = 1
        private val SEVERITY = Severity.FATAL
        val ISSUE: Issue = Issue.create(
                ID,
                DESCRIPTION,
                EXPLANATION,
                CATEGORY,
                PRIORITY,
                SEVERITY,
                Implementation(
                        MissingContributorDetector::class.java,
                        Scope.JAVA_FILE_SCOPE)
        )
    }

    companion object {
        const val DAGGER_MODULE_ANNOTATION_QUALIFIED_NAME = "dagger.Module"
        const val DAGGER_CONTRIBUTESANDROIDINJECTOR_QUALIFIED_NAME = "dagger.android.ContributesAndroidInjector"
        const val HOME_FRAGMENT = "com.dagger.module.HomeFragment"
    }
}
```

A file to test this detector:

**ModuleOne.kt**

```
@Module  
abstract class ModuleOne {  
  
    @ContributesAndroidInjector  
  abstract fun isAnnotated(): HomeFragment  
  
    abstract fun shouldBeAnnotated(): HomeFragment  
  
    abstract fun notAnnotated()  
}  
  
abstract class ModuleTwo {  
  
    abstract fun okIsNotAnnotated(): HomeFragment  
}
```

The lint report showing flagged items:

[image]

Comment: That would solve an issue when the annotation is missing on already existing functions. But in my case I want to find missing functions, that should be included (and annotated with ContributesAndroidInjector) in classes annotated with `Module`